# UIRefreshControl on TableViewController subview of UIView

Tags: uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I am trying to do a pull-to-refresh action on a collapsable tableview that is a subview of a UIView.

I have searched StackOverflow and found an answer, but it still doesn't work.

Have anyone faced this problem before? I've attached a picture of the code I did, hoping someone will help me out with it.

[image: snippet of the code]

Answer (score 0):

Which UIControlEvent you have used against **forControlEvents** ?

Comment: UIControlEventValueChanged

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem, I accidentally set the bounces to NO instead of YES, thats why it is not able to pull downward